# Shell Script Ruby Command Not Found

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a shell script that is running under crontab that kicks back the error: "Ruby: Command not found" for the invocation of a Ruby script. I have no issue running this script when I invoke it through a terminal it is only when running under crontab that I have issues.  Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT: Using RVM, running RHEL.

Comment: How are you invoking the script from cron?

Comment: <cron timing info> <fullpath>/script.sh

Comment: Try dumping `printenv` to some file for both cases, while executing from crontab and directly executing it. My guess is crontab's `env` would not have the path to the actual Ruby executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/path/to/rvm 2.1 do /path/to/script.rb args...
```

because `cron` doesn't have your `rvm` settings, you need to start your script through `rvm` script (not `rvm` function) to explicitly choose a Ruby. (Obviously, replace `2.1` with whatever Ruby you want to execute under.)

Comment: How much of the rvm path should I include? /home/<my username>/.rvm? or should I go further in to the version?

Comment: You need to find the `rvm` executable, wherever it was installed. Since I don't know how you installed `rvm`, I can't tell you exactly. For example, on the Ubuntu I administer, I installed it globally, so it sits in `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`. On my Mac, it is in `/Users/amadan/.rvm/bin/rvm`.